# Using Chrome.ahk library to fill out a field inside an iframe

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, selenium-chromedriver, autohotkey

Hello can anybody help me with trying to edit a field inside an ifram using CHROME.ahk

The following code works when I create an IE ojbect. This is the part I use to fill in the field.

```
workoder := test
frame := pwb.document.parentWindow.frames("uxtabiframe-1068-frame")
frame.document.GetElementsByName("ff_workordernum").item[0].Value := workorder
```

How do I do this using the chrome.ahk library.

and it doesn't work. I have tried several methods. Can anybody please help

I have trid this:

```
PageInstance.Evaluate("document.parentWindow.frames('uxtabiframe-1068-frame').document.GetElementsByName('ff_workordernum').item[0].Value = 'test' )
```

I get an error. I tried

```
iframeJs =
(
var iframe = document.getElementById('uxtabiframe-1068-frame');
var test2 = iframe.contentDocument..GetElementsByName('ff_workordernum').item[0].Value = 'test';
)
PageInstance.Evaluate(iframeJs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem with the first try you are trying to get the property "document" of the Iframe here:

```
frames('uxtabiframe-1068-frame').document
```

However Iframes have no such property, it's called "contentDocument"

I think this is silly and confusing that it is like this, just "document" makes more sense and should be the standard.

Also in the first try there is an opening double quote but there isn't a closing one.

In the second try there is a repeated "." here:

```
iframe.contentDocument..GetElementsByName
```

You only need one of them.

And also with the second try you've tried to assign a variable over multiple lines, everything must be on the same line and you can do that by using "`n" which is an escaped newline character.

Comment: Hi thanks for your feedback. I added the double quotes and tried putting contentDocument but it get an error. Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'frames') at <anonymous>:1:23.
If you know any other way to access a field in an iframe, I am willing to try it out.
the iframe id is uxtabiframe-1068-frame and here is a different field from the one above using JS Path document.querySelector("#textfield-1580-inputEl")

Comment: Sorry for the late response, that error says that 'frames' is undefined, meaning there is no function called that. You want to instead use `document.getElementsByTagName("iframe").` In the bottom example I see the mistake that GetElementsByName has a plural because it returns an array of elements that fit the description, not just the first one it finds. Try `document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0]` to get the first iframe it finds on the page.

Comment: so what should work is: `document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentDocument.GetElementsByName("ff_workordernum")[0].value = "test"`